# Comment exprimer « je ne présente ici que les points de plus grand intérêt » dans le titre d'une section d'un CV ?

Tags: anglais, vocabulaire, curriculum-vitae

*Highlights* est un mot particulièrement utile sur un CV en anglais. Par exemple, une section nommée *Work Experience (Highlights)* ou *Teaching Activities (Highlights)* indique de façon concise que la section est un résumé qui ne contient que les points les plus notoires ou éminents, et dignes du meilleur intérêt.  Comment exprimer la même idée de façon à peu près aussi concise en français ?

Les possibilités que j'envisage mais n'apprécie pas :
*résumé*, *extraits*, *extraits choisis*, *points éminents*, *faits notables*.

Comment: S'agit-il des points les plus importants dans ta vie professionnelle en général, ou des points les plus en rapport avec le poste pour lequel tu postules ? (Cf. [la réponse de Laure](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/7823/5)).

Comment: @Gilles: Ce ne sont pas les miens, et je ne sais pas, même si je pense que les deux coïncident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En complément des autres réponses je viens de penser à *sélection*, qui peut être mis entre parenthèses comme *highlights*.

Answer (score 5):

Que penses-tu de "expériences **principales**" par exemple ? 
Majeures pourrait convenir, mais sonne moins bien à mon oreille

De manière générale, sauf C.V. universitaire de 100pages, les C.V. sont des résumés, sinon, nul besoin d'entretien !

Comment: Je suis en fait à la recherche d'une formulation qui marche quel que soit le type d’éléments listés. *Principaux* convient dans beaucoup de cas, mais j’attends de voir s'il n'existe pas mieux.

Answer (score 5):

Je penche plus pour quelque chose comme expériences professionnelles (points-clés). C'est assez clair formulé ainsi.

Answer (score 2):

De nombreux exemples de CV en ligne proposent une rubrique **compétences spécifiques**. Si « compétences » ne convient pas, tu pourrais envisager des variantes avec **spécifique** : points, expériences, intérêts,...

Comment: Je pense que c'est différent. « Compétences spécifiques » signifie que la sélection a été faite en fonction du poste pour lequel le CV a été rédigé. « *Highlights* » pourrait signifier ceci (mais j'écrirais plutôt « *most relevant* »), mais en général désigne plutôt une sélection représentative des éléments les plus importants.

Answer (score 2):

Je n’arrive pas à bien saisir l’idée. Vous parlez des expériences  professionnelles les plus importantes/ à signaler? « Expérience professionnelle principale »/ « Expérience professionnelle résumée ».  De toute façon, on sait déjà qu’à partir d’un certain âge, on ne peut plus mettre dans le CV qu’un résumé de tout ce qu’on a fait pendant notre vie; on sait qu’il n’y plus de place que pour ce qui a été vraiment vraiment important (voire adapté au poste auquel on postule). Alors il ne faut peut-être pas le spécifier puisque évident.
D’autre part, ce que vous voulez mettre en valeur sur votre CV c’est plutôt vos points forts ? Là, on parle des compétences/habiletés acquises/développées  tout au long de votre vie professionnelle.  Dans ce cas-là je mettrai « Atouts ».

Answer (score 1):

Je pense que de parler d'«expérience pertinente» serait pertinent. Ça communique la plus grande importance des points présentés, du point de vue de l'employeur.

Answer (score 0):

Expérience professionnelle :
***Principalement*** réalisée dans deux entreprises :

- 1 Sté A (la plus récente)
- 2 Entreprise B

Expérience éducative : 
***Les plus importantes*** actions ont été effectuées sur deux domaines :

- 1 Encadrement de jeunes durant *x* années (chronologiquement)
- 2 Cours de ...